# How do I automate this code without having to push play?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I automate this code in excel without having to "view code" and pushing play?

```
Option Explicit
 Sub sortononecol()
 Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("C1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
 End Sub
```

1.) View code

2.)run

I need this to be automated

Comment: You can assign a keyboard shortcut to your macro.

Comment: You can also add a custom button to your toolbar that runs it. But without you explaining what you mean by "automated" that's about the best anyone can help you with.

Comment: (1-view code,2-run) try instead-Alt & F8 should give you the list of macros to run if they are in regular modules. Assign the macro to a shape can be another solution. Is it possible the code is in the worksheet module?

Comment: If you want it to be automatic (not triggered manually) then you need to decide what event will cause it.  Do you want it to do it every second? or when the worksheet is opened? or closed? or when you edit a cell?